# Count from multiple columns and rows simultaneously in SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by

I have a table of matches which look like:

```
Match Win Lost
MOne   T1  T2
MTwo   T2  T3
MThr   T1  T3
MFou   T3  T4
```

I need to find the total matches played by every team and the output should be like this:

```
Team  Total_matches
T1      2
T2      2
T3      3
T4      1
```

I know about SUM() and GROUP BY clauses but not able to do it on multiple columns. 
 Any help would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `union all` to unpivot the data and then aggregate:

```
select team, count(*)
from ((select win as team
       from matches
      ) union all
      (select lost as team
       from matches
      )
     ) m
group by team
```